# Expectation value of the exponential family distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, machine-learning

In generalized linear model ,the distribution of response variables follow the exponential family distribution form :

$$
P(x\mid \eta)=h(x)\exp\big(\eta^Tt(x)-a(\eta)\big)
$$

My question is, when discuss the expectation value of the exponential family  ,why we always focus on $\mathbb{E}\big[t(x)\big]=\dfrac{\partial a(\eta)}{\partial\eta}$ ? Is there any relationship between $\mathbb{E}\big[x\big]$ and $\mathbb{E}\big[t(x)\big]$ ?

Comment: For some exponential family distributions, $t(x)=x.$ See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_exponential_family).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know some exponential family distributions, $t(x)=x$, but not always,right ? If $t(x)\neq x$, how can we deal with $\mathbb{E}[x]$ ?